# ASP.NET CORE 3.1 JQuery Pass Parameter to .load('@Url.Action Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

Razor page works well, except for passing the id to the controller. I can get the partial view to refresh the divAppInfo just fine. I am having problems with the "$("#divAppInfo").load('@Url.Action( "and passing a parameter to it.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">App</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group">
        <select id="formApp" name="formApp" class="form-control" asp-items="@appSelectList" onchange="GetAppInfo()"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="divAppInfo"></div>

<script>
function GetAppInfo() {
    var s = $("#formApp option:selected").text();
    $("#divAppInfo").load('@Url.Action("GetApplicationInfo", "B2BPortal", new { area = "B2BPortal"})?id='+s);
}
</script>
```

My Controller shows

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetApplicationInfo(int id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Changed: 
var s = $("#formApp option:selected").text();

To:
var s = $('#formApp').val();
```